# Why we need custom bridge to communicate with others Dockers container using name? Why the default's bridge cannot do it please?

Tags: docker, containers

I'm working on Docker container and I find it strange the default network prevent from communicate between container using the name, 
thanks for any hint

Comment: what do you mean by ' the default network prevent from communicate between container using the name' ? generally speaking as long as the containers inside the same network they will be able to talk to each other by default.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [docker's embedded dns on the default bridged network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400603/dockers-embedded-dns-on-the-default-bridged-network)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Containers on the default bridge network can only access each other by IP addresses, unless you use the --link option, which is considered legacy. On a user-defined bridge network, containers can resolve each other by name or alias.

From official [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge)

Technically, there is nothing stopping docker to resolve the container names on default bridge network. I think it is just a decision that is made by docker team to force users to create bridge networks consciously. So that they know what they are doing and securely use it for production.